# Docker error message: "denied: requested access to the resource is denied"

Tags: linux, docker, dockerhub

I'm trying to login from a Linux terminal to docker and pushing an image. However, I keep seeing the error message "denied: requested access to the resource is denied".

There are hundreds of Google hits (and Stackoverflow questions) that explain the following solution:

1. Login in to docker using "docker login -u username".
2. Build your image like "docker build -t username/servicename ."
3. Push your image "docker push username/servicename"

According to hundreds of thousands of posts, this is the solution and everyone seemed happy with that.

Except that it's not working properly for me. I keep getting the error.

I have set up the following configuration:

- In .docker/config.json, "credsStore" is set to "pass".
- From the terminal, I set up pass in the following way:
  gpg --generate-key
  pass init UID
  pass insert docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check

I will say that occasionally on logon I got a warning saying that I shouldn't use the password and create access tokens instead, because the console will have full access to my account when using the password. Whenever I got this warning, I was able to push my image to docker hub.
I conclude that whenever I don't get this warning, my logon does not succeed properly (even though the console prints out "Login Succeeded") and thus I don't have the rights to push the image. That being said, I cannot determine any reason why the login resulted into a different outcome at times.

So, I think the error is about me not setting up the configuration properly and I hope that anyone can point me the right way to getting this fixed up.

Just for reference:

- I tried logging out explicitly, closing/reopening the terminal, and then logging in again.
- I tried logging in by explicitly adding docker.io as command parameter.
- I tried deleting and reconfiguring the entire gpg/pass configuration.
- I tried logging in with an access token.
- I tried setting the "Default Repository Privacy" to "Private" (default is "Public") on Docker Hub.
- I tried tagging the image explicitly as "latest" or "v1.0".
- I tried pushing by explicitly targeting the tagged "latest" or "v1.0" image.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem.
I solved it modifying push command like this:

```
docker push "DOCKER USER NAME"/"IMAGE NAME":"TAG"
```

Example: `docker push johnsmith/my-python-img:v2.0`